# Ideas on filtering out consistent time series data

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, signal-processing

So I have two subsets of data that represent two situations. The one that look more consistent needs to be filtered out (they are noise) while the one looks random are kept (they are motions). The method I was using was to define a moving window = 10 and whenever the standard deviation of the data within the window was smaller than some threshold, I suppressed them. However, this method could not filter out all "consistent" noise while also hurting the inconsistent one (real motion). I was hoping to use some kinds of statistical models and not machine learning to accomplish this. Any suggestions would be appreciated! 
[noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz5Ad.png)
[real motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXsYY.png)

Comment: You could first remove the zero points. Then, it looks like you have series of distinct events? Maybe you could filter each event on the min and max value? or preferably on the standard deviation but calculated separately for each event?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I was thinking roughly the same. To compare each max and min and see if the majority of difference are within the tolerance. I will come back if that does not work.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I am using KS test to compare the cluster of noise against the uniform distribution, and mute the bursts if it it uniform(noise)

Comment: You could answer your own question if you want (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), giving a little more details, for instance I don't know what KS means...

Answer (score 0):

The Kolmogorov–Smirnov test is used to compare two samples to determine if they come from the same distribution. I realized that real world data would never be uniform. So instead of comparing my noise data against the uniform distribution, I used scipy.stats.ks_2samp function to compare any bursts against one real motion burst. I then muted the motion if the return p-value is significantly small, meaning I can reject the hypothesis that two samples are from the same distribution.